# How can I get an array/loop through all suites of NSUserDefaults I got access to?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

How can I get an array/loop through all suites of NSUserDefaults I got access to?

e.g. Im searching for a method like (imagined) `NSUserDefaults.allPossibleSuitsThatCouldBeRead()`

background for debbugging purposes I wanna keep it very generic.
Should I try with all appGroups from my info.plist or is there an easier way?

Comment: What about ```dictionaryRepresentation``` ? Never used it but it might do the trick :)

Comment: That’s ehat I’m using but it returns a flat list!? Not sure if all would be there. I’ll test it then :)

Comment: I thought maybe there’s a nicer api